# costructor of function confusion

Tags: javascript, prototype

in this case

```
var A = function(){
    this.d = 123;
}
A.prototype.c = 999;
A.prototype.d = 333;
var B = (new A()).constructor;

console.log(""+B);

console.log(new A().d); // 123
console.log(new B().d); // 123
console.log(new A().c); // 999
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(new B()).c); // 999 why?
```

A and B share same constructor
but B is not A, why has same prototype of A?

in this case

```
var A = function(){
    this.d = 123;
}
A.prototype.c = 999;
A.prototype.d = 333;
var B = A.constructor;

console.log(""+B);

console.log(new A().d); // 123
console.log(new B().d); // undefined
console.log(B.d); // still undefined
console.log(new A().c); // 999
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(new B()).c); // undefined
```

B is constructor of A and not of his instance

what is B? how to access constructor of A with no instance of A?

Comment: Related  [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: if B is constructor of A, why the last line? c is property of A.prototype and not of constructor or.. what?

Comment: @Liam sorry, i can't get it, how this solution solves my answers?

Comment: I've retracted my close vote. It explains the first example but not the second

Comment: This is likely useful here [Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `new A()`, you create a new `A` object whose prototype is `A.prototype`. When you ask for **`(new A()).constructor`**, you're accessing the `constructor` property from the prototype chain of that `A` instance; this would be `A.prototype.constructor`.

`A` itself is a `Function` object. That is to say: `A` is an instance of `Function`. When you ask for **`A.constructor`**, you're accessing the `constructor` property from the prototype chain of that `Function` instance; this would be `Function.prototype.constructor`.

In your first case, `B` and `A` are references to the exact same function. It's totally expected that the results of `new A()` and `new B()` would have the same properties and the same prototype chain.

In your second example, `B` is the `Function` constructor -- i.e., a function that constructs functions. Calling `new B()` creates a new `Function` object. Thus, the result of `new B()` has none of the same properties as an `A` instance.

Comment: Good answer, explains it well.

Comment: so, if you set B = A.constructor you are cloning A?

Comment: @MatteoRubini `A` is an instance of `Function`, so `A.constructor` is the `Function` constructor (just like how `new A()` is an instance of `A`, so `(new A().constructor` is the `A` constructor). When you do `B=A.constructor` you're storing the `Function` constructor in `B`. If you ask for the `constructor` property of any function, you'll get the `Function` constructor (e.g., try `(function(){}).constructor`).

Answer (score 2):

To tell the difference you might want to look at what is `A` and what is `new A()`:

```
c = new A(); // This is an instance of A. The constructor property is A.
console.log(c.constructor) // function() { this.d = 123; }
console.log(new c.constructor()) // Creates another instance of A.
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(new c.constructor())) // A {c: 999, d: 333}

var c = A; // This is a function. The constructor property is a base Function.
console.log(c.constructor) // function Function() { [native code] }
console.log(new c.constructor()) // Creates instance of base Function.
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(new c.constructor())) // function Empty() {}
```

Without the `new` operator on your custom constructor (`A`) you are not creating an instance of `A`.

More information on `new` operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's already answered, I did not see it made clear that B is A (oops, its late missed apsillers mentioned it):

```
var A = function(){};
var B = (new A()).constructor;
console.log(B===A,B===A.prototype.constructor
  ,A.prototype.constructor ===A);//true true true
//Something.prototype.constructor is a circular reference as constructor
//references Something
console.log(A.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype
  .constructor.prototype.constructor === A);//true
```

Constructor comes with prototype and is set to the constructor function but you can overwrite it (usually done when inheriting so you usually see it repaired after inheriting)

```
Child.prototype=Parent.prototype;
//Child.prototype.constructor now incorrectly refers to Parent
console.log(Child.prototype.constructor===Parent);//true
//repair constructor
Child.prototype.constructor=Child;
```

More on inheritance, constructor functions and prototype [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).

Since all objects have a prototype (unless created with Object.create(null)) all objects have a constructor property pointing to the function that created them:

```
console.log([].constructor===Array);
var arr = new [].constructor(1,2,3);//same as new Array(1,2,3)
console.log(arr);//[1,2,3]
//the following temporarily casts the string to String
console.log("hello".constructor===String);//true
//same with numbers
console.log(1..constructor===Number);//true
console.log(function(){}.constructor === Function);//true
```

Comment: and why B.prototype = A.prototype; console.log((new B()).constructor === A); // true      but    A = function(){console.log('hey!')} ----> new B(); // do nothing ?

Comment: solved... constructor is just a link and, when changed, does not affect original "class" construction